# DB Synchronization between main and DR site

Tags: synchronization, postgresql

I hope I am asking this question in the correct section.

I have an environment setup for my application which consists of  master / slave Postgresql databases. The master and slave are being replicated using streaming replication. Everything works good.

Right now I am in the process of setting up a DR environment, which is a replica of my main site. What I would like to know is what would be the best way have synchronization setup for my main and DR site, so if one day I need to switch to my DR, the data in the database is the latest.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Use an additional streaming replica, plus WAL archiving to a secure offsite system.

In your position I'd use:

- Streaming replication from the master; plus
- PgBarman full and incremental backups; and
- Puppet or other configuration management to keep the live and DR site's config consistent

Comment: Thank you for your response, could you please provide more detail on the first point (Streaming replication from the master) you provided.

Comment: @user3513075 I don't get it - you're already using streaming replication, what's different about adding another node?